# Android fixed header on ListActivity

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I am quite new to ListViews, that's to begin with.

Anyways, what I want to do, is obviousy to hold a button or whatever on top of my list, which is created programmatically and with only one xml file. The xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".Main" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eventName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eventTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in Main.java I simply define my ListAdapter

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Main.this, fillMaps,
                    R.layout.main, from, to);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

So basically I do not have a `<ListView/>` in my XML file.

Comment: I am unclear as what you want. A button fixed on the top your activity or a custom listview?

Comment: @RohanKandwal I am sorry for being unclear. I want a button fixed on the top. I.e if I scroll my generated list, the button stays on the top.

Comment: u need to inflate that layout in listview.

Comment: use `relative layout` with button as `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

Comment: @RohanKandwal that just gives me a ton of buttons that overlay my list.

Comment: do you want a `button` at the top with a custom `listview`?

Comment: @RohanKandwal I guess that is the case. My main.xml is the custom listview as I understand.

Comment: @user2367219 i have updated my answer please check

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F2B1DBF3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<Button
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:id="@+id/button"
..
>
<LinearLayout

..
android:layout_below="@+id/button"
>...

</RelativeLayout>
```

**update**

did you want something like this?

[image]

Comment: Does not work, I get a button for every item I have,

Comment: Yes, I wanted that what is in the picture.

Comment: see this link here it has full tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Thank you, going to check it out

Comment: @user2367219 ya sure if that answer helps you then you can mark the answer as solved by clicking on the check mark.